# How to compare Excel files (.xlsx) with Kdiff3?

Tags: excel, atlassian-sourcetree, kdiff3

I added Kdiff3 as my external diff tool in Source tree as shown in the figure.  [image]

But when I select two commits from Master and click on External Diff from Actions, kdiff3 is showing non-readable text as shown.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a chance you're trying to diff a binary file instead of a text one? If so, then it's not a problem of kdiff or ST, it's just those files are not comparable in tools like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare excel files in SOurceTree, I used WinMerge (along with plugin, to compare excel files) which is a free tool from http://freemind.s57.xrea.com/xdocdiffPlugin/en/

Comment: after install winmerge+plugin, open files and then go to menu `Plugins` > `Edit with Unpacker` select file unpacker = `CompareMSExcelFiles` and OK

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to compare two Excel files. Such files are stored in binary format and are not comparable using tools designed for comparing text files (such as kdiff or winmerge).

To compare two Excel files use Excel itself: https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Compare-two-versions-of-a-workbook-by-using-Spreadsheet-Compare-0e1627fd-ce14-4c33-9ab1-8ea82c6a5a7e

Comment: can we use this Spreadsheet compare inside Source tree? If not, are there any free tools we can use to compare two excel files inside Source tree?

Comment: There're two different questions that you're asking: 1. how to configure an external tool to work from ST. 2. how to use Excel (or other tool to actually compare two files). For the first one use the External Diff Tool dropbox and Diff Command/Arguments to configure that. For the second one, try to see whether you have a file located something like "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\DCF\SPREADSHEETCOMPARE.EXE". If not, then you should try to find another tool for Excel file comp.

Comment: Thank you.. Is there any way that we can add the path C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\DCF\SPREADSHEETCOMPARE.EXE to our External Diff tool?

Comment: According to https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-487, ST gets the external tools list from git config and the latter doesn't support different tools for different extensions. So you'll have to launch it manually I guess. But keep looking, there's a chance you'll find a way to do that somehow.